# Grid Column Width - mix *(star), Auto and fill left space

Tags: wpf, grid, width, alignment

I have a Grid width following Column Definitions:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="320" MaxWidth="450" Width=".32*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200" Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200" Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/> <- (4) should fill all available space
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="250" MaxWidth="300" Width=".20*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The problem is that setting width to Auto on column (4) zeros it's width and last column is next to third one. I'd like to have last column aligned to right edge of app and first three to the left.

I also can't set (4) width to star(*) - obviously it stretches relatively to first and last column.

I've been trying for a while with horizontalalignments but as a result - content is not filling the columns width. I could maybe bind content width to column width or sth like that, but I'm curious whether there is some easy way to achive the (4) column fill all left space.

Comment: I am trying to understand your question. Why the following statement is a problem? from your post:"I also can't set (4) width to star(*) - obviously it stretches relatively to first and last column."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you didnt quite undestand the (*) which stands for weighted average.

so for your case.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="320" MaxWidth="450" Width="3*"/>
     <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200" Width="Auto"/>
     <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200" Width="Auto"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
     <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="250" MaxWidth="300" Width="2*"/>
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

if you wish to make the column (4) small reduce the * weightage and increase where you like.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thx for the answer. I know the weightages - I just wrote it differently. If I write .3* and .5* instead 3* and 5* - there will be no difference at all. Problem is that if I set (4) column to let's say 5* it will not decrease its size to 0 if I resize window to small size. I want 4 column not affect the size of the others - just fill the left space - if there is any.

Comment: @Joe as far as i know it should cuz when you decrease the size.. it decreases the weightage ratio...try removing all `Auto` and setting min and max width for the same

Comment: It works with Auto for me, but good to know about the Min and Max attributes.