# wpf Auto Width UserControl in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, listbox

Hello guys I create this `UserControl`

```
<UserControl x:Class="Pass.ConexionControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid MinWidth="300">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8D9395"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Gainsboro" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" MinWidth="30" MaxWidth="30"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White"/>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="5"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="7"></TextBox>

        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Click="Button_Click_2"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Click="Button_Click_3"></Button>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The control is displayed correctly in the Visual Studio designer

When I try to add it to a `ListBox` in `Window` the width of the control contracts

I add the property `MinWidth` with 300, but, It is not the behavior I need

My `MainWindow` is like

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pass" x:Class="Pass.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="listMain" Margin="5">
            <local:ConexionControl />
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In this case when the window is resized the list control will also change the size.

**I need the user control resize regards the ListBox**

In my user control I have 1 Grid with 2 Columns first column must rezise, second must keep size.

What should I change to accomplish this?

Comment: set your width of `ListBox`, then in user control set your first column width to `Auto`, second to `*`

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10244767/2470362)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,164,86">
  <uc:UserControl1 />
</ListBox>
```

In your user-control :

```
<Grid>
...
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Now when you resize your window everything will expand/contract accordingly.